# To what degree do large lakes influence precipitation levels compared to the ocean?

Tags: meteorology, precipitation, rainfall, mesoscale-meteorology

I was wondering what percentage of precipitation could be estimated to have been contributed by large lakes such as the Great Lakes or Lake Baikal in the immediate vicinity of said lakes (say, within 50-100 miles of the lake)?

And generally speaking, what overall percentage of precipitation can be attributed to oceans as opposed to all other sources combined (lakes, rivers, etc)?

Comment: I presume you are aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake-effect_snow ?

Comment: @gansub Estuaries have "lake"-effect snow, too. I wonder if OP wants to restrict the question to freshwater bodies.